# NetworkOnMainThread Exception in getView method while loading images to Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I need to fetch images from url's and Load them into gridview. I am getting network on Main thread exception in the getView method of my ImageAdapter class which extends Base Adapter. How can i solve this using a Separate thread or an Async Task.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   {           

    ImageView imageView;

    try {

            URL url = new URL(Product_ItemsURLs[position]);

            InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();

            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(380,380));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

            return imageView;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

}
```

Comment: Usually you get this error when you are performing some n/w related operation in main thread try to use Async task or use thread

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` to load images into your `GridView`

Comment: I moved the code to an Async Task and Now i am getting array index out of bound exception.

Comment: In which part of the code? We really need your new code to answer that (or really a new question since the original issue is now fixed, and question answered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below is what is causing the issue. It's performing a network operation. From honeycomb onwards android doesn't allow network operations on the UI Thread.

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src");
```

You need to use an `Asynctask` to download the drawable, and set the drawable to the view in your `onPostExecute` (which runs on the UI Thread).